# Can sip client pass additional info for CDR rows of IPPBX devices

Tags: sip, voip

Is there any provision by which  SIP clients can pass unique values to IPPBX devices during call related events.
And will such values passed to IPPBX devices show up in its CDR ?

we tried to lookup if such options are available in Grandstream IPPBX and Microsip Client, but could not find any such options.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer sending OPTIONS message (just because of simplicity) with some custom (X-) header lines. Depending on the purpose INFO might be also good and easy to use. You probably won't be able to use it with PABX that is not quite open source though.